# In a Jenkins job, a way to update Schedule cron expression using an API, without posting whole XML

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to modify the  schedule remotely, by sending a parameterized cron expression, so this value should get updated. As per my knowledge, only way to do is modify the XML and pass it  as the payload. Is there any simplified way to do  this?

```
<triggers>
<hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
<spec>05 01 * * *</spec>
</hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
</triggers>
```

[image: Schedule]

Comment: If you use declarative pipelines you can define the periodic trigger in the Jenkinsfile and thereby change it by pushing commits to the repo

Comment: Hi M B
Thank you for the response , it's just a standalone maven  Jenkins job.